# expo MediaLibrary doesn't read files from Iphone

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to get list of audio files from the phone. It works fine with android but doesn't want to detect anything on my iphone device. I saw few topics with similar problem but couldn't find solution. Does anyone knows how to make it work on iphone?

```
   const scanMusicFiles = async () => {
     
     let media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
       mediaType: MediaLibrary.MediaType.audio,
     });
 
     media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
       first: media.totalCount,
       mediaType: MediaLibrary.MediaType.audio,
     });
     console.log('media', media);   
    };
```